# Colorbox isn't working, although all settings are correct

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm having a bit of an issue over here. I've installed the Colorbox module like it should (install the library & the module, like described in the documentation), the HTML is generated as it should, but the colorbox module doesn't activate at all...

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="path/to/image" class="colorbox">
  <img src="path/to/image" />
</a>
```

but still, I don't see any colorbox...
Is there something I forgot or oversaw on my install?

Comment: do you see an overlay or you are taken to the image with out the colorbox.?

Comment: When I click on the image, I'm redirected to the image URL, so a new page with just the image on it.

Comment: where have you placed the above link. and what version of colorbox are you using?

Comment: Do you have the colorbox plugin also in sites\all\libraries\?

Comment: The Colorbox formatter is activated using a View and I'm using the 7.x-2.0 version.

Comment: @cayerdis, Jep, that's what I said in my question on the first line. The .js-files are detected by the website, so I think I've included them correctly!

Comment: have you configured colorbox to behave in that way. in colorbox setting you need to enable that. you can visit admin/config/media/colorbox and check if that is enabled. It would be the first one

Comment: That's what I said in my question... All settings according to the documentation are correctly

Comment: which version of colorbox are you using?

Comment: have you updated recently? in colorbox module says Changes since 7.x-2.1:

Important: When updating to this version of the Colorbox module you need to update the Colorbox plugin to v1.3.21.1 or later as well.

Comment: please note that colorbox 1.3.26 and 1.3.27 had an error due to which the script was not working with older version of jQuery so you should download the latest version.

Comment: Hi @cayerdis, please provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it. It was indeed an outdated module... :)

Comment: Trying to get the attention of the admins…… why was this close? looks like a relative well asked question..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with colorbox:

1. Do you have the latest version? If you updated recently to version from colorbox notice that in the module page says Changes since 7.x-2.1: Important: When updating to this version of the Colorbox module you need to update the Colorbox plugin to v1.3.21.1 or later as well.
2. Mohammed Shameem mentioned in the comments above is valid. He remark the following: please note that colorbox 1.3.26 and 1.3.27 had an error due to which the script was not working with older version of jQuery so you should download the latest version.

However, the version of colorbox included in the Drupal 7.x colorbox module is NOT STATED.